# How do I embed Youtube videos in Phabricator?

Tags: php, phabricator

In the remarkup reference located at :
https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/remarkup/

> If you set a configuration flag, you can embed media directly in text:
>
> remarkup.enable-embedded-youtube: allows you to paste in YouTube videos and have them render inline.
> This option is disabled by default because it has security and/or silliness implications. Carefully read the description before enabling it.

I have attempted to set this flag like so:

`./bin/config set remarkup.enable-embedded-youtube true`

yielding:

```
./bin/config get remarkup.enable-embedded-youtube
{
  "config": [
    {
      "key": "remarkup.enable-embedded-youtube",
      "source": "local",
      "value": true,
      "status": "set",
      "errorInfo": null
    },
    {
      "key": "remarkup.enable-embedded-youtube",
      "source": "database",
      "value": null,
      "status": "unset",
      "errorInfo": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I have restarted phd and apache2 to no avail. I have also upgraded phabricator and i'm running the latest off the stable branch.

Answer (score 0):

The above works. My youtube URL was improperly formatted all along. *sigh*

Comment: Could you share the final remarkup of youtube link? Do you just use simple link?